# Does a fiddle provide enough information to "Describe the specific problem"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, close-reasons, jsfiddle

I'm specifically talking about this question [How to force background down whole page when content overflows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19340928/542251). A couple of people have said this should be closed because it:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe
>   the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it

Now the question does not provide any useful code for this, but the fiddle does. Is an off site resource (like a fiddle) adequate enough to "describe the specific problem"? Or should the user be encouraged to put the code (or at least some of it) into the question?

My concern is that this won't be searchable going forward and will become un-useful to future users, but at the same time, questions that just dump code onto a page are generally a pain to answer.

So I'd prefer to answer this question but does it prove unhelpful to future visitors?

Comment: Always provide the same information in the post.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, I would guess that a subset of the more useful elements would be adequate?

Comment: @Liam As long as it's still enough to replicate the problem, yes.

Answer (score 9):

Not everyone can access JSFiddle. (It's blocked by corporate policy where I work for some reason.)  People need to put the relevant parts of their code in their question.  If they don't know where the error is, they're going to have to either post the whole thing or do some debugging on their end to try and narrow it down before posting.

Comment: I would wonder why they blocked it. I hope it's not because the workers used it too frequently...

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Best-of-Email-Fun-in-Alaiowaska,-HP-Cannot-Comment,-Mumps-Tech-Support,-and-more.aspx

Comment: @Calmarius The message I get when I try to go to JSFiddle just says that the site has "certain security risks." I imagine this was a fear-based policy decision.